# How to change the structure of my output by efficiently using iterator or any other thing?

Tags: java, optimization, foreach, iterator

I want to restructure below code

```
Map m=request.getParameterMap();
    Set s = m.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();

    out.print("<h1> Your Input Based on MapParamters</h1><br><br>");
     while(it.hasNext()){

            Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry = (Map.Entry<String,String[]>)it.next();
            String key             = entry.getKey();
            String[] value         = entry.getValue();

            out.println(key + " : ");
            if(value.length>1){    
                    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                        out.println("<li>" + value[i].toString() + "</li>");
                    }
                }else
                        out.println(value[0].toString()+"<br><br>");

     }
```

the output is like

```
ISBN :
-1
-2
-3
-4

Title :
-5
-6
-7
-8

Price :
-9
-10
-11
-12



But I want the output like

ISBN : 1
Title : 5
Price : 9

ISBN : 2
Title : 6
Price : 10

ISBN : 3
Title : 7
Price : 11

ISBN : 4
Title : 8
Price : 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the trick

```
Map m=request.getParameterMap();
Set<String> keys = m.keySet();
ArrayList<String[]> valuesArr = new ArrayList<>(m.values());

out.print("<h1> Your Input Based on MapParamters</h1><br><br>");

int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < keys.size(); j++) {
    for (String key : keys) {
        for (String value : Arrays.copyOfRange(valuesArr.get(i), j, valuesArr.get(i).length)) {
            out.println(key + " : " + value + " ");
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
    i=0;
    out.println("<br/>")
}
```

[Check the output of my code in command line version.](http://ideone.com/fyyC0Y)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either you change the input to have such object. Or

1. Create an Java Pojo say Parameter
   2. While iterating over the loop populate this pojo according to your requirement.
    3. Now you are good to print it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Map m=request.getParameterMap();
Set s = m.keySet();
Iterator it = s.iterator();

System.out.print("<h1> Your Input Based on MapParamters</h1><br><br>");
ArrayList<String> outputStrs = new ArrayList<String>(); 

for(Object keyObj : s){
    String key = (String) keyObj;
    String[] val = m.get( key );
    for(int j=0;j<val.length; j++)
    {
        if( outputStrs.size() < (j+1))
            outputStrs.add( key+" : "+val[j]);
        else
        {
            String existing = outputStrs.get( j );
            existing+= "  " + key+" : "+val[j];
            outputStrs.set( j, existing);

        }
    }
}
for(String outputStr: outputStrs)
    System.out.println( outputStr +" <br> " );
```